# How I do target Framework 4.8 when I have VS2022 installed

Tags: .net, frameworks, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-2022

Since I have installed VS2022, I can not create a new project targetting framework 4.8.

Whenever I click "New project" from within VS2019, it seems to invoke VS2022 which leaves me with no choice but NetCore or Framework 5. Both don't work for me.

I start VS2019:

[image]

Now I click "Create new project":

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

So, there seems to be no way to do what I want.

[image]

"Installing other frameswork..." does not help.
I already have them installed, so their installer only offers me to restore / modify / repair them.

[image]

What else could I try?

Edit: Yes, in the installer, Framework 4.8 is activated:

[image]

Comment: If you run the VS installer and go into the selected options for your VS install, are the relevant .net framework workloads (whether that means desktop, web-server, or whatever) installed? By workloads, I mean the bunch of checkbox options (note: there are multiple tabs for high-level vs fine-grained options)

Comment: Yes, it was acrtivated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should select the **Windows Forms App (.NET Framework)** project template. If you select the **Windows Forms App** project template , then it will only have .NET Core or.NET 5/6 as targets.
[image: Project Template NET Framework]

Then you can select the .NET Framework version you need for your project
[image]